# How to not repeat annotations for Bean Validation?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I use Spring MVC with form validating. User entity has field login:

```
@Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_PATTERN)
@Size(min = 4, max = 50)
private String login;
```

But I want to use this annotations with another fields, for ex., with RegisterData.login. So I created another annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_PATTERN)
@Size(min = 4, max = 50)
public @interface Login {
}
```

And now mark fields with it. But that doesn't work. Is it a way to use that type of *'inheritance'*? Or should I repeat myself?

Comment: This is called a *meta-annotation*, and it's not supported in the general case (some software, such as Spring, specifically handles it). If Groovy is an option, you could use an annotation collector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the declaration of the `@Login` annotation as a constraint, by adding the `@Constraint` annotation. From the [Bean Validation specification](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintcomposition):

> Composition is done by annotating a constraint annotation with the composing constraint annotations.

Since your composed constraint does not require a validator, you can set the `validatedBy` property to an empty array.

```
@Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_PATTERN)
@Size(min = 4, max = 50)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Login {

    String message() default "Incorrect login";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

}
```